# rewrite XPATH expression negation without using NOT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to allow `<applic>` on `<table>` but not on `table` descendants. I'm writing the XPATH in a text file that gets imported into a database. For some reason the database is flagging some or all XPATH with a `not` in the expression as invalid. Is there a way to write the following without `not`? (I tested with an online XPATH checker/validator and this worked as expected.)

`//ancestor::table//applic/not(parent::table)`

```
<table>
    <applic>table applic
        <assert displayclass="assert displayclass"/>
        <evaluate displayclass="eval displayclass"/>
    </applic>
    <tgroup>
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>entry<applic>entry applic</applic><ftnote/></entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

First `applic` is OK, `applic` in `entry` not allowed.

Incorporating both responses solved the problem and enabled me to fix the other invalid paths:

```
//parent::table//applic[not(parent::table)]
```

Comment: `not()` can be used only in a *predicate*, e..g `applic[not(parent::table)]`.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. So `not()` must be within the brackets? This would not be valid: `not(//language/@language[translate(normalize-space(.), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" , "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = "en"])`

Comment: It would not be valid as a *path*. It may be a valid *expression* in another context.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `applic` elements that are direct children of `table` elements with the following expression:

```
//applic[parent::table]
```

The `ancestor::` axis would, on the contrary, select all `applic` elements that have a `table` ancestor. In your case this would selects both nodes.